# Redux Saga call not taking localStorage tokens

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I have recently started learning Redux Saga and Redux Toolkit and I have come across a redux-saga and toolkit problem.

I am trying to make a login system that places the tokens in your system and then whenever the app loads for the first time it fetches the user details from the database, if it returns a 401, then the user isnt logged in and I set the return as undefined. This gives me the ability to hide components that arent supposed to be visible. Is this the best direction to take it, do you have any suggestions?

It appears that the data fetched after Axios and placed into the localStorage is not used by a handler?
Is it doing the next in line tasks asynchronously?
Would I have to use an actionChannel there? If so how would I implement it, it states 'pattern' but it becomes very confusing with what that is since they dont use redux-toolkit with createSlices and use redux only?

from login data gets submitted through formData, the watcher saga sees that I have hit `logInUser` and sends it to the right handler. The `handler` then takes the data, sends it through axios using the `yield call(requestLogInUser)` with the action as payload. The response from axios is then placed in res, from which the two tokens are extracted and set in local storage (which works).

After which the `yield call(handleGetCurrentUser)`; should start the getCurrentUser handler and actually get the user details data from the database using the tokens set in localStorage.

However what happens is that the data does not get called instead it just gives me 401, meaning it didnt find/try to grab the tokens from localStorage even though axios asks for it. This makes me thing its because its asynchronous and firing off the yield call somehow before the tokens are set? I could not find it trying the action at all using the redux dev tool, but I noticed it firing it off because of console.log and it returning the 401 on that api endpoint.

My submit button in **Login.js** to show the dispatch of formData

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(logInUser(formData));
  };
```

My **User.js** file with all the **handlers**:

```
export function* handleLogInUser(action) {
  try {
    const res = yield call(requestLogInUser, action.payload);
    yield localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data.access_token);
    yield localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", res.data.refresh_token);
    yield call(handleGetCurrentUser);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export function* handleGetCurrentUser() {
  try {
    console.log("in request get user");
    const response = yield call(requestGetCurrentUser);
    const { data } = response;
    yield put(setCurrentUser({ ...data }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export function* handleSetCurrentUser(data) {
  try {
    console.log("in request set user");
    yield put(setCurrentUser({ data }));
  } catch (error) {}
}
```

My **user.js requests** file which contains the Axios requests

```
export function requestLogInUser(formData) {
  return axiosLogInInstance.post(`auth/token/`, {
    grant_type: "password",
    username: formData.email,
    password: formData.password,
    client_id: "asdfasdfasdfdfsdfassfsfWJFdQ",
  });
}

export function requestGetCurrentUser() {
  return axiosInstance.get("/user/currentUser/");
}
```

My **axiosInstance**

```
const baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    accept: "application/json",
  },
});
```

My **UserSlice.js** file that contains the slice

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    logInUser(state, action) {},
    getCurrentUser() {},
    setCurrentUser(state, action) {
      const userData = action.payload;
      return { ...state, ...userData };
    },
  },
});
```

finally **Rootsaga file**

```
export function* watcherSaga() {
  //authentication/user
  yield takeLeading(logInUser.type, handleLogInUser);
  yield takeLatest(getCurrentUser.type, handleGetCurrentUser);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code about sagas and react is right, the problem is the **axiosInstance**, in the code, axios only get the *localstorage* one times when the instance be created, add the axios request interceptors

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request(config => {
  config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("access_token")
  return config
}, null)
```

Comment: oh god it was exactly that finally fixed it, thank you so much :-)